# Dynamic File Path for image in Django

Tags: django, django-media

I'm trying to generate dynamic file paths in django. I want to make a file system like this

```
hierarchy:
```

> ```
>  --user_12
>   --channel_14
>    --program 2
>     --image1.jpg
>     --image2.jpg
>    --program 1
>     --image1.jpg
>     --image2.jpg
>  --user_14
>   --channel_13
>    --program 1
>     --image1.jpg
>     --image2.jpg
> ```

When a user want to upload image it will upload the image to the corresponding program folder.if program folder does not create it will automatically create a folder and store image..

my image path will look like this: media/images/john/johnchannel/birthday/img1.jpg  ( where john=user,johnchannel=channel,birthday=program,images is the pre created folder where all image file should be stored)
I am very new in django. urgent help needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic File Path in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135556/dynamic-file-path-in-django)

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for something like this?

**misc.py**

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    """ creates unique-Path & filename for upload """
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s%s.%s" % ('img', instance.pk, ext)

    return os.path.join(
        'images', instance.user.username, instance.channel, instance.something, filename
        #images/     john/                johnchannel/       birthday/          img1.jpg
    )
```

**models.py**

```
from misc import get_upload_path

class MyThing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    channel = models.CharField(max_length=100) # johnchannel
    something = models.CharField(max_length=100) # birthday
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

Comment: my image path will look like this: media/images/john/johnchannel/birthday/img1.jpg  ( where john=user,johnchannel=channel,birthday=program)

Answer (score 1):

When using an ImageField in a Django model, you can specify a callable in the `upload_to` keyword argument: [See the FileField docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField)

So create a function that you'll point `upload_to` at, which can generate all your subdirectories as needed.