# Django image upload is not working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to upload image through Django admin site. But it is not working i have installed PIL package. But it is displaying : `<django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage object at 0x8a92f0c>/mcDonalds.jpg`

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
projectDirPath = path.dirname(path.dirname(__file__)) 
storeImageDir = FileSystemStorage(location=projectDirPath + '/couponRestApiApp/static')
storeImage = models.ImageField(upload_to=storeImageDir)
```

And the static dir is empty..is i am doing something wrong...

Comment: First of all, `upload_to` should be set directly to the upload path or to a callable (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)). Please, also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135556/dynamic-file-path-in-django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : `storeImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")`

This will append your file name ex: abc.png to images/abc.png and then set media dir where you want to store images for ex: `yourAppDIR/static/images/....`

And set the URL :

```
url(r'^tosomeThing/(?P<path>.*)/$', 'django.views.static.serve',
     {'document_root': MEDIA_URL, 'show_indexes': False}),
```

Set media URL in your settings file..to

```
MEDIA_URL = projectDirPath + '/couponRestApiApp/static/'
```

when you will upload any image it will get stored in the images dir of your app