# Dynamic File Path in Django and South

Tags: python, django, dynamic, path, django-south

I'm having a problem setting a dynamic path to my imageField.

This is my models.py

```
class Imagen(models.Model):

def get_upload_path(self, filename):
  return os.path.join(
  "img/experiencias/experiencia_%d" % self.id_experiencia.id, 'ficha' + '_' + filename)

nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
id_experiencia = models.ForeignKey(TipoExperiencia)
imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to= get_upload_path)
caption = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True)
alt = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

This is a solution that I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135556/dynamic-file-path-in-django)

This actually works fine when updating objects, but when I try to insert new elements, the inserts fail because in that moment self does not exists.

I've tried another solution [here](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2007/07/31/uploading-images-to-a-dynamic-path-with-django/#working_solution) whose proposal is overriding the ImageField method to customize upload_to.

The problem is that I use South and it's quite difficult [to manage custom fields](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customfields.html)

I use Django 1.5. I would like to know if exists any easy way to manage dynamic file path in django

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can override the save method to move the file to the correct path.

```
class Model(models.Model):
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    # your logic here to change the file location
    return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get away here with [Unipath](https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath).

[Unipath usage](https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath#id15)