# Django file storage for different absolute media paths

Tags: django, upload, scale, media

We'd like to store user uploaded image files according to (e.g.) their model instances' primary keys on different servers/absolute paths. Example: We'd place the first 1000 files on server A, the next 1000 files on server B, and so on. It's a form of horizontal scaling that fits our needs.

The idea is to use a dynamic uploaded_to path as described in this SO question:
[Dynamic File Path in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135556/dynamic-file-path-in-django)

However, when using an absolute path (beginning with "/"), Django throws a SuspiciousFileOperation error: "The joined path is located outside of the base path component (MEDIA_ROOT)".

So, I'm currently looking for a way of permitting virtually arbitrary absolute paths in the uploaded_to callable.