# Django - should ImageField be built-in to same app, or implemented in a separate app?

Tags: django, django-models, imagefield

For example, there are two applications `cars` and `houses`, both of them currently have a `models.ManyToManyField` to a model with a `models.ImageField(upload_to='img/[APP_NAME]`.

Instead of copying and pasting that snippet of `ImageField` code, is it better to split the image upload into a a separate application and import it? What should it look like?

Comment: Considering the [DRY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry) approach, making a new app for images makes sense.

Comment: So far the only way that comes to mind is to have a separate model in the `images` app, one model for each app that requires images. Unless I want to put the images from all the apps into one directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no clear answer on your question. It highly depends on what you want to achieve.

With making a separate app, that only knows about images, you will have the following problems:

- You want different `upload_to` for your `cars` and `houses`. You will need to set it dynamically. [Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135556/dynamic-file-path-in-django)
- Your image model (the one with `ImageField`) will know about both `cars` and `houses`, via `related_name` property. I don't find it to be any good. To get rid of the backreferences, you can specify `ManyToMany(..., related_name="+")`. Note: `"+"` means no related name given and it shouldn't be auto-generated. But the reasonability of removing it is also questionable.
- One more app, that does... well, nothing. One more dependency for each of your apps.

On your place I would just leave both model images, one in `cars`, another in `houses`. That's considering the amount of boilerplate code you will have to write and amount of problems you would create for yourself out of nowhere.

Comment: That's pretty much my reasoning to keep it the way it is. Since this is considered acceptable, I'll leave it that way