# Uploading to User Defined Folders Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am making an app where users can upload files to an AWS S3 Bucket. Each user, when signing up, gets a folder within the `media` folder based on their `userID` How to I allow my users to upload their projects to that their folders? The files upload just fine, but to a folder named `None`. This seems like an easy answer, but I cannot seem to find it.
Here's my views.py

```
def new(request):
    title = "Add New Project"
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        raise Http404
    form = ProjectForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.fileLocation = request.user.id
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        return redirect("/dashboard/")
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "title": title,
    }
```

Here's my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    fileLocation = None
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    sell = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=fileLocation, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And here's my forms.py (just in case)

```
from django import forms
from .models import Project
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'image',
            'sell',
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the request param to your modelForm init .. and use that (assuming you will then have access to request.user)  to set the location field specific to that user

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific

Comment: sorry I wasn't that detailed, but this question has already been answered in several different ways.  Can you check this link for a duplicate issue: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135556/dynamic-file-path-in-django). Also you may want to use ImageField directly instead of FileField to have a better handle over image dimension, filetype checks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your models.py.

Add this:

```
def fileLocation(instance, filename):
  return 'uploads/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.owner.username, os.path.basename(filename))
```

remove this:

```
fileLocation = None
```

and your user's file should go into `uploads/<username>/<filename>`.

As BobbyC mentioned, you should use ImageField instead of FileField