# Django FileField move file following upload

Tags: python, django, django-models

There are several questions around this topic but not one that I've found that suits what I'm trying to do. I want to be able to upload a file to a model and save that file in a nice location using the model instance attributes like pk. I know that this stuff gets set after `model.save()` so I need to write a custom save to do this, but I can't figure it out. Here is what I have:

```
class UploadModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Call standard save
        super(UploadModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if 'uploads' in self.image.path:

            initial_path = self.image.path

            # New path in the form eg '/images/uploadmodel/1/image.jpg'
            new_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images', 
                self._meta.model_name, self.pk, os.path.basename(initial_path))

            # Create dir if necessary and move file
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(new_path)):
                makedirs(os.path.dirname(new_path))

            os.rename(initial_path, new_path)

            # Do something here to save the new file to the image field

            # Save changes
            super(UploadModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What do I have to do to the `image` field to get it to reference this new file location, and set all the useful attributes to it like `image.path`, `image.name`, `image.url` etc?

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/files/#using-files-in-models) say that the above is all I should need to do but this just results in the `image` field pointing to a file that doesn't exist. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135556/dynamic-file-path-in-django) related question and tried the [snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1129/) mentioned in one of the answers but I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out after a lot of searching and finding [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15590#comment:10) old documentation ticket that has a good explanation.

```
class UploadModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Call standard save
        super(UploadModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if 'uploads' in self.image.path:

            initial_path = self.image.path

            # New path in the form eg '/images/uploadmodel/1/image.jpg'
            new_name = '/'.join(['images', self._meta.model_name, str(self.id), 
                path.basename(initial_path)])
            new_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images', 
            self._meta.model_name, self.pk, os.path.basename(initial_path))

            # Create dir if necessary and move file
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(new_path)):
                makedirs(os.path.dirname(new_path))

            os.rename(initial_path, new_path)

            # Update the image_file field
            self.image_file.name = new_name

            # Save changes
            super(UploadModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now I read the [docs for this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/files/#using-files-in-models) it looks totally obvious :) but I do think the explanation could be made more descriptive. Hopefully this will save someone some time!

Comment: You should just pass a callable to `upload_to=`, as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Comment: Thanks yes that looks like a better solution