# Django doesn't update the ImageField path

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to upload a profile picture when model instance is being created. I want my profile picture to be stored in a folder, that is named according to the instance id, hence once the picture is uploaded I need to create a new dir and move the picture there.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372256/django-filefield-move-file-following-upload), which suggests overriding the default `save()` method in the model, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234917/django-how-to-get-self-id-when-saving-a-new-object), that proposes to use `post_save signal` to save the new file twice.

My current code looks as follows:

```
class Emp(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField("Photo", blank=True, null=True, default='default_avatar.png')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Call standard save
        super(Emp, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.photo.path:
            initial_path = self.photo.path

            new_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                                'profile_picture_of_emp_{0}/{1}'.format(self.pk, os.path.basename(initial_path)))

            # Create dir if necessary and move file
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(new_path)):
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(new_path))
            os.rename(initial_path, new_path)
            # Save changes
            super(Emp, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

So this actually moves the file and creates `new_path` correctly, however, the `self.photo.path` stills refers to the old location and I can't figure out a way to update this new path. The same happens with `post_save` signal as it doesn't update the path of moved file. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `self.photo = new_path;super(Emp, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` at end ?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
my_new_path = 'profile_picture_of_emp_{0}/{1}'.format(self.pk, os.path.basename(initial_path))
self.photo = my_new_path;
super(Emp, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

at the end.

Comment: I get `DataError: value too long for type character varying(100)` (my picture name is 15 chars long), therefore I **assume** it sets a `photo.name` instead of a `path`

Comment: Sorry, I checked it and it actually updates the path, however I get the latter error during the save()

Comment: Add max_length=200 and try after migrate

Comment: haha I was about to write that! It works! Thank you very much! :)