# Django FileField upload_to assistance

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and trying to adapt to the OOP of Python. Could someone explain why the following is saving in a folder called 'None'? I want to upload an audio file in the admin page. This file gets stored in its own folder with the 'Vocab name'

```
class Vocab(models.Model):
module = models.ForeignKey(Modules, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
number = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

class VocabContent(models.Model):
vocab = models.ForeignKey(Vocab, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
audio = models.FileField(upload_to=vocab.name)
```

Running the following on shell.

```
>>> from module.models import Modules, Vocab, VocabContent
>>> vocab = VocabContent.objects.get(pk=1)   
>>> vocab.vocab.name
'Numbers'
```

Numbers is the value i am looking for.

Comment: so what's not working, what is going on? any errors? What have you tried etc...?

Comment: It works...BUT. It creates a folder 'None' and not the current instances vocab name. In the example above the folder would be 'Numbers'

Comment: change upload_to, to `self.vocab.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the way you reference `vocab.name` is not defined when your model migration is run. I can't explain precisely why this happens but a solution would be to use a callable as your `upload_to` to evaluate it at runtime and get the value correctly, much like this other answer: [Dynamic File Path in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5135635/1245235)

So, for you, you could have something like:

```
import os
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join("%s" % instance.vocab.name, filename)


class VocabContent(models.Model):
    vocab = models.ForeignKey(Vocab, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)  # Important to NOT put the parenthesis after the function name
```

Which would result in a path that concatenates the `vocab.name` to your file name for every new file.

Comment: Worked like a charm...
Just a questions for my Python learning.
Any reason why the function is outside the class and not within it?

Comment: @Leo505 AFAIK it doesn't make a difference, but you'd need to add a `@classmethod` annotation to the function if you move it inside the model and reference it as `VocabContent. get_upload_path` in your field.