# Django Image model with dynamic upload_to function using generic relation

Tags: python, django, django-models, image-uploading, django-generic-relations

I am creating an Image model which will be used by other models via generic relation. For example, Newsposts and events will have images. Below is the sample Image model

```
class Image(models.Model):
   description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_storage_path)

   content_type=models.ForeignKey(ContentType,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

This will store the image in only one directory. 
 However the problem is I cannot figure out how can I write a dynamic `upload_to` function that will store the images in the corresponding directories, e.g `images/news/` and `images/events`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `upload_to` handler takes [two arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), `instance` and `filename`. You can inspect the `instance` to find out which content type the object is associated with:

```
def get_storage_path(instance, filename):
    # This is just an example - you'll need to use the right name
    # depending on the model class.
    if instance.content_type.model == 'news':
         # Generate filename here
    else:
         # Generate different file name here
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to save one file at several locations: Checkout [Django Custom Storages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-file-storage/).

If you just need to set the upload_to folder dynamically according to the related object: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135556/dynamic-file-path-in-django) is a possible duplicate thread which answers your question.