# Django: Multiple models on the same table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a recipe/cookbook application (something like [cookpad](https://cookpad.com/) or [allrecipes](http://allrecipes.co.uk/)) for a personal project.
I have a model for image like so:

```
class Image(Model):
    type = (("R", "Recipe"), ("P", "Profile"), 
            ("E", "Embedded"), ("B", "Base"))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    type = models.CharField(choices=type, max_length=1, default="B")
    image = VersatileImageField(
        upload_to=FileNameGenerator(prefix="images"),
        placeholder_image=OnDiscPlaceholderImage(
            path=join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "images", "default.jpg")
        ),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

I want to use one table only to store all image. But store it to different place for each different type.

Example:

- Base image would be at images/xxx.jpg
- Profile's image at profiles/xxxx.jpg
- Recipe's image at recipes/xxx.jpg
- etc..

The only way I know how, is to make it an abstract model and extend it. But it would create many table (ProfileImage, RecipeImage, etc..)

If I use proxy I cannot change/override the behaviour of image field.

Is there a a way to extend models but save it to the same table in database?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135556/dynamic-file-path-in-django

Comment: You don't need separate models here. You just need a dynamic upload_to parameter - which you already seem to have, with FileNameGenerator. Why can't you extend that to use different directories as well as filenames?