# python PIL and Image scaling

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to make sure an image that will be saved stays inside the border of my specific dimensions and scales down if any of its dimensions exceed these specific dimensions.

I will be using a gallery for my website using django and the width and height of it is certain, If I use crop while saving an image to keep dimensions under control, it crops a part and as a result doesn't act as I wish.

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [resize image on save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623698/resize-image-on-save) also [image-resizing-with-django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164930/image-resizing-with-django)

Comment: Those don't seem like (exact) duplicates to me as OP is asking to resize image within constraints rather than asking for resizing in general.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look at http://thumbnail.sorl.net/ (especially http://thumbnail.sorl.net/template.html#options), it will solve this and many other problems that you may encounter later.