# Django filebrowser - resize before upload

Tags: django, image, resize, python-imaging-library, django-filebrowser

Is it possible to resize image before upload using django filebrowser without keeping original image size on server ?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140483/django-imagefield-setting-a-fixed-width-and-hight

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519716/django-resize-image-during-upload)

Comment: [this](http://davedash.com/2009/02/21/resizing-image-on-upload-in-django/) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create pre_upload callback that will resize your image before saving.

```
from filebrowser import signals

def pre_upload_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    Receiver function called before an upload starts.
    """
    print "Pre Upload Callback"
    print "kwargs:", kwargs
    # your code HERE
signals.filebrowser_pre_upload.connect(pre_upload_callback)
```

[Filebrowser documentation on signals](http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html#example-for-using-these-signals)

Alternatively, if pre_upload hook doesn't work (because the file is not there yet) you can use post_upload hook, and modify the file in place.