# How can I resize an image file uploaded with Django using an ImageField Model?

Tags: django, image, upload, resize, photo

What is the most straightforward method to resize an image file uploaded via a Django form as an `ImageField`?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Use PIL for the job: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio

Comment: you need to use an external library or an app to achieve that as django does not have any pre-defined methods for what you are looking to do.

Comment: Is there any way to re-open this closed question so that I can share my modern solution? (Django 2.0 and Python3.6).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57637103/4816270

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I was annoyed that I couldn't find a complete working example, only bits here and there. I managed to put the solution together myself. Here is the complete example, I put it in clean() method of the form (you can also override models save() method, in the completely same way - changing ImageField's file property).

```
import StringIO
from PIL import Image

image_field = self.cleaned_data.get('image_field')
image_file = StringIO.StringIO(image_field.read())
image = Image.open(image_file)
w, h = image.size

image = image.resize((w/2, h/2), Image.ANTIALIAS)

image_file = StringIO.StringIO()
image.save(image_file, 'JPEG', quality=90)

image_field.file = image_file
```

Comment: Thanks for this example but I don't understand everything... What is "info" ? Otherwise, in python 3.x it's io.StringIO(...)

Answer (score 7):

You could use PIL and resize the image in YourModel.save() method.

Examples:

[resize image on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623698/resize-image-on-save)

http://djangosaur.tumblr.com/post/422589280/django-resize-thumbnail-image-pil

http://davedash.com/2009/02/21/resizing-image-on-upload-in-django/

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Comment: Yeah, added in my post :)

Comment: +1 for suggesting PIL

Comment: Not a single link is a complete example for my use case, I had problems integrating the code in my previous attempts.

Comment: This answer would be better with code examples in the answer and not just links to other websites that may be down at the time you try to click the link.